# Does an IDE identify all compile errors before running?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been wondering about something lately.It is about the errors which an IDE like netbeans show us while we type the code(Let's assume java).I want to know whether an IDE is capable of identifying all the compile time errors while we type? It means if we run the code with an IDE, are we supposed to get only the run time errors?

Comment: Are you trying to run code with compile errors?!

Comment: No I just wanted to figure out that if Netbeans doesn't warn you about any error before we run, whether it is an assurance that there is no compile errors.

Comment: It will not let you compile if there are errors. Thats like saying ' compile this "blah blah blah{}()()();". How does that 'piece of code' match the spec and expect to be compiled into anything.

Comment: @PaulSullivan, what if he wants to compile with javac directly? GUYS it is not hard, his question is - will Eclipse highlight all compile time errors in his code? (as red) He doesn't care about runtime exception being highlighted.

Comment: @jsn - err... read the question again. at what point is javac mentioned. and why are runtime errors mentioned?

Comment: @PaulSullivan Serenity now. Serenity now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It means if we run the code with an IDE, are we supposed to get only the run time errors?

It depends on the IDE. For example, in Eclipse, if there are any compile-time errors when you try to run the code, it will warn you about this, but still allow you to continue if you want to. At that point, any code which successfully compiled will execute as normal - but any methods or classes which *couldn't* be compiled will have the failure represented as an exception thrown by the generated code. Exactly where the exception is thrown depends on the kind of compilation failure.

*In general*, most of the time you should be running code which compiles without any errors. While the ability of Eclipse to "fake it" is occasionally handy, it would be a bad idea to get into the habit of using it instead of fixing up errors as you go, in my view.

EDIT: If the question is "Will I always know if there are any compile-time errors" then yes, assuming you don't blindly dismiss the warning that Eclipse gives you. I don't know of any IDE which will *silently* let you run code with compile-time errors in. (You should also look at the Errors view, or whatever your IDE happens to provide, of course.)

Comment: to be fair Jon the user stated errors - warnings are usually depreceation warnings and not (as yet) compile time errors

Comment: @PaulSullivan: Yes, I was referring to errors too. I didn't refer to warnings at all, other than that Eclipse will "warn you" when you try to launch code with errors.

Answer (score 1):

If the IDE supports it, it will tell you all the errors in the code, before you even click "Compile". This applies to all IDEs, if I'm not mistaken, some will also give you any errors that the compiler itself returns.

It really all depends on your IDE, settings, and sometimes compiler.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is based on what IDE you are referring to and its settings.

No. `EditPlus` doesn't show any compile time errors.

Eclipse/Netbeans, based on settings output will be different.

Comment: Nambari ,Isn't EditPlus just a text editor. I was asking about IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

If your IDE is capable it will look at what you have written and see if it matches the spec BUT...

Certain times what you write wil be unable to be checked i.e. explicit casting of an object to a Type where you pass in the wrong type i.e. typecastexception.

Somethings CAN be known by a compiler i.e.

```
int a = "abc"; // obviously wrong because "abc" is a string and not an int(eger) and COMPILE time
```

Somethings CANNOT be known (EDIT: if you pass a true into findTheRunTimeError you WILL get a RUNTIME error)

```
int a;

public someFunction(object passedIn, bool findTheRuntimeError)
{
     if(!findTheRuntimeError)
     {
          return;
     }
     a = (string)passedIn;// obviously wrong cast because passedIn is cast to a string which is not an int(eger) and RUNTIME
}
```

There is now way for the compiler to know what is going to be passed and cast so therefore it will always be a runtime error.

Comment: Yeah I get you. But doesn't that mean that it identifies the compile time errors before we run? Only the run time errors will be left..?

Comment: Thats correct runtime errors will ONLY be found when you run the piece of offending code i.e. see EDIT

Comment: As Jon Skeet correctly stated you may get compile time warnings (which will not stop compilation) - this is almost always as a result of metadata in the library that is picked up by the compiler to show code is depreceated i.e. old code that may someday be removed or cause bugs

Comment: @PaulSullivan, that is not true. Try to use an explicitly null reference. Eclipse will tell you that you have a runtime error. Javac will happily accept it.

Comment: @PaulSullivan: No, I didn't mention compile-time warnings. My answer talked about compile-time errors.

Answer (score -2):

As you type, your IDE compiles your code after you finished a word or something like that. That way it is able to show you coding mistakes like non-existant variables or other compile time errors.
Your IDE uses your configured Java compiler to do that. When you try to compile incorrect code using javac on the command line it also gives you information on your mistakes. The IDE does the same, parses the information it gets from javac and highlights them in your code.